# Alternative Solandra for cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, sql-like, solandra

Anyone knows an alternative to Solandra in Cassandra?

I can't use "like" clause, and in my case i'll use always.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Datastax provides a "tweaked" version of Apache Solr (which saves data directly into Cassandra instead of flat files) to do real-time full-text search. It's called *Datastax Enterprise Solution*. Of course is not free.

As an alternative, you can couple Cassandra with an Elastic Search cluster but it's kind of heavy just for text search.

Last but not least, try to implement yourself a full text search using Lucene as engine and some hand-made Cassandra tables for storage, good luck though.

Comment: Actually datastax its reaaaaaaally expensive.

Comment: 2 Ways:
1. Buy datastax.
2. Learn engeneer skills, to build yourself.

Comment: Or look at this video from Cassandra Summit SF 2013 : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E92u4FXGiAM. By the way, it is not that hard to manage Lucene indexes yourself in Cassandra. The hand made solution might not be as performant as the generic solution offered by Datastax, or might be more performant because completely tailored to your requirements

Comment: I'll really need to do every index for every new query i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options to bring advanced search capabilities with Cassandra:

- Datastax **Solr** as already mentioned
- Elassandra = **ElasticSearch** on Cassandra. https://github.com/strapdata/elassandra and http://www.strapdata.com/ It's a good product, we use it in my company. The community edition is free and the latest release combine Cassandra 3.11 with Elasticsearch 5.5. You will see on their website that there is some free trial hosted solution you could use to test.
- Stratio **lucene** plugin
  https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index It's free, it works, we also use it in my company. It's just a jar to drop in the Cassandra lib directory.

Of course, for very basic search needs, you can have a look at SASI too.